# Cross platform HTML select control

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

The appearance and behavior (look) of HTML select control (specially combo box) is not similar among different browsers. What are the good libraries or CSS templates available to fix this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by is not similar among different browser ? the look of it or the handling of events etc ?

Comment: could you post some examples in which behaviour the differ from each other ? You could easily set the styles for your select and apply it. So you have your own unique look. but maybe you should try css rest. maybe this is what you are looking for

Comment: http://www.designdim.com/2011/07/10-important-jquery-selectboxdropdown-plugins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that you can "fix". Each platform and browser may provide its own user control to the select box, just like their look differs from OS to OS. An alternative would be to use a "replacement", user - developed control. On that note: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: sexyselect.net is dead

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fix it as there is nothing wrong in it. It's dependent on the operating system and the browser the person is using. 
You can use jQuery UI Select widget : http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-selectbox-widget/
But generally it's something that is meant to be that way.

Any particular reason you want to do it?

Comment: I need a consistent look and feel throughout my site among different browsers.